# Dos to get next day date

Tags: dos

Is there an easy way in dos to get next days day in this format: `mm/dd/yyyy`?

In [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) it is:

```
DateAdd("d",1,dtmStart)
```

Thanks

Comment: Short answer - No. There is no native date arithmetic in DOS or Windows Command Prompt (CMD.EXE). There are batch routines that have been written to parse dates and perform date arithmetic, but they are fairly complex. It involves parsing a date string and computing julian days, adding days, and then converting back to normal date string.

Comment: [cmd and DOS are not the same thing](http://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 0):

DOS has %DATE% variable to store date information which can be called from command prompt. You may use string manipulation to display string as you see fit. Some example that show %DATE% as MM/DD/YYYY format.

```
ECHO %DATE:~3,2%/%DATE:~0,2%/%DATE:~-4,4%
```